# Loading assets cross-domain with SSL or non-SSL option

Tags: assets, config, ssl

Here's a unique situation. I have three websites. All assets are stored at the domain of the first site:
domain.com/files/*

The first two sites run completely over SSL. No problem.
The third site needs to have the **option** to load either over SSL or non-SSL. This is entirely thanks to the authoritarian governments of countries like China, which may block a site, no matter the content, if it can only load over SSL.

In my config.php, I have this:

```
'@assetBaseUrl' => 'https://site1.domain.org/files'
```

If I change this to exclude **https://**, Craft does not create proper URLs for images and files. I also tried **//site1.domain.org**, but that doesn't work either.

Is there some setting I can use for @assetBaseUrl that will work across the board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like `'@assetBaseUrl' => $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https://site1.domain.org/files' : 'http://site1.domain.org/files'` which checks for a secure request.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks so much!